# how to access ubuntu host from ubuntu guest

Tags: server, apache2, virtualbox-networking, owncloud-server

I installed  Own Cloud 7 in my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop using Apache server.
I can able to access Apache server from localhost.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box.
Now  i need to access the Own Cloud 7 running on the host machine from Virtual Box Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Change connection type in Networks setting of virtualbox to bridge mode, and you can access it by ip of the client os.